# If numbers in list are equal to n, print out their indices

Tags: python

The Task:

> You are given two parameters, an array and a number. For all the numbers that make n in pairs of two, return the sum of their indices.
>
> **input** is: `arr = [1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5]` and `n = 7`
>
> **output**: `11`
>
> since the perfect pairs are `(4,3)` and `(2,5)` with indices `1 + 3 + 2 + 5 = 11`

So far I have this, which prints out the perfect pairs

```
from itertools import combinations


def pairwise(arr, n):    
    for i in combinations(arr, 2): # for index in combinations in arr, 2 elements
        if i[0] + i[1] == n: # if their sum is equal to n
            print(i[0],i[1])
```

Output:

```
4,3 2,5
```

However does anyone has tips on how to print the indices of the perfect pairs? Should I use numpy or should I change the whole function?

Comment: You've got the values so you can get the indicies by using arr.index(): i.e. arr.index(i[0]) and arr.index(i[1])

Comment: As a side note you can simplify your loop with a one liner: `list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == n, combinations(arr,2)))`

Comment: @Gerik if I add your code to the end:  return arr.index(i[0]) + arr.index(i[1])  it does not return the right values

Comment: I think this is no longer relevant but what do you mean by "not the right values"?  What are they returning?  The purpose of the index function is to obtain the location of value in a list: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm

Comment: For example this input [1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5],7) should equal 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating combinations of array elements you can generate combinations of indices.

```
from itertools import combinations


def pairwise(arr, n):
    s = 0 
    for i in combinations(range(len(arr)), 2): # for index in combinations in arr, 2 elements
        if arr[i[0]] + arr[i[1]] == n: # if their sum is equal to n
            # print(arr[i[0]],arr[i[1]])
            # print(i[0],i[1])
            s += i[0] + i[1]
    # print(s)
    return s
```

Comment: Good approach. Don't use `sum` as a variable name. I think you can write that in one line. `return sum(i[0]+i[i] for i in combinations(range(len(arr)), 2) if arr[i[0]] + arr[i[1]] == n)`

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! So the in the first line you are saying: for index in combinations for the range of the len of the array (you iterate through the array)  right?

Comment: Only when I put this in : [1, 1, 1],2),1) the output is 6 but should equal 1. Also for input ([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],1) - output is 48 but should be 10..

Comment: No, for arr=[0,0,0,0,1,1] and n=1 you get: arr[0] + arr[4] = 1, arr[1] + arr[4] = 1, arr[2] + arr[4] = 1, arr[3] + arr[4] = 1, ... That's 48

Comment: Same for arr=[1,1,1] and n=2: arr[0] + arr[1] = 1, arr[0] + arr[2] = 1, arr[1] + arr[2] = 1. 0 + 1 + 0 + 2 + 1 + 2 = 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictonary mapping the indexes:

```
def pairwise(arr, n):
    d = {b:a for a,b in enumerate(arr)} #create indexed dict
    for i in combinations(arr, 2): # for index in combinations in arr, 2 elements
        if i[0] + i[1] == n: # if their sum is equal to n
            print(d[i[0]],d[i[1]])
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/VengefulMundaneSoftwareengineer)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than generating combinations and checking if they add up to `n`, it's faster to turn your list into a dict where you can look up the exact number you need to add up to `n`. For each number `x` you can easily calculate `n - x` and then look up the index of that number in your dict.

This only works if the input list doesn't contain any duplicate numbers.

```
arr = [1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5]
n = 7

indices = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(arr)}
total = 0
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    remainder = n - x
    if remainder in indices:
        idx = indices[remainder]
        total += i + idx

# the loop counts each pair twice (once as [a,b] and once as [b,a]), so
# we have to divide the result by two to get the correct value
total //= 2

print(total)  # output: 11
```

---

If the input *does* contain duplicate numbers, you have rewrite the code to store more than one index in the dict:

```
import collections

arr = [1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5, 2]
n = 7

indices = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    indices[x].append(i)

total = 0
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    remainder = n - x
    for idx in indices[remainder]:
        total += i + idx

# the loop counts each pair twice (once as [a,b] and once as [b,a]), so
# we have to divide the result by two to get the correct value
total //= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the naive approach here:

- process each element of the array with its indice
- for each element test for all elements after this one (to avoid duplications) whether their sum is the expected number and if it is add the sum of their indices

Code could be:

```
def myfunc(arr, number):
    tot = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if val + arr[j] == number:
                tot += i + j
    return tot
```

Control:

```
>>> myfunc([1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5], 7)
11
>>> myfunc([2, 4, 6], 8)
2
```